# Change font of HTMLbody in C#

Tags: c#, html, fonts

I am using mailitem.HTMLBody to process the text of an email body.

The entire body of the email can be accessed through mailitem.HTMLBody.

How can I change the font of the entire email body in C#? e.g Set font size as 10.5 and font as Consolas

```
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)selection[1];

mailItem.HTMLBody = "<font size= 10>";
```

This does not work.

Comment: I hope that's not the real example that you're testing with - HTML tags without any text content won't render *anything*. You're changing the font for an empty page. (And, as @Spudley mentioned, `font` is deprecated. )

Answer (score 3):

No.

Don't use `<font>` tags. This tag has been obsolete for a very long time now.

Instead, use a CSS stylesheet. This would be a separate file which you'd include (it can also be embedded in your main page using the `<style>` tag in your header, but it's better practice to have it as a separate file)

To set the font globally io your page using CSS, you can do this:

```
body {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have added the CSS style sheet, How do I call the stylesheet from my function which accesses the HTML body?

Comment: is it like mailItem.HTMLBody="<Stylesheet1>"?

Comment: @thinkcool - it's `"<style>body {font-size:10px;}</style>"`, and it goes in the page header section, not in the htmlbody.